# Asp core add controller to swagger api explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

How can I make my controller visible in the swagger api explorer? Before the update, I didn't have to use the `[ApiController]` attribute. But now the controllers are not visible anymore in the explorer. Is there a way I can make the controller visible in the explorer without using the attribute?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using conventional rounting, Swashbuckle won't be able to find your controllers and actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I will use the attr but i will suppress the default model validation

```
        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Disable the default model validation
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });
```